# How to access name of key in dynamically created json in action script 3

Tags: json, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a json object coming from my java code as string :

```
{
  "ABC":["ABC","XYZ","pqr"],
  "OMG":["ABC","XYZ","pqr"],
  "Hello":["ABC","XYZ","pqr"]
}
```

on decoding it as 
myObj : Object = JSON.decode(result);
Now how do I access key names like ABC, OMG, HELLO...??

Answer (score 0):

Try this will help you.

When you want properties in object use `for-in` loop or you want value use `foreach` statement.

```
var obj:Object = {
    "ABC":["ABC","XYZ","pqr"],
    "OMG":["ABC","XYZ","pqr"],
    "Hello":["ABC","XYZ","pqr"]
};

var jsonText:String = JSON.stringify(obj);
var jsonObj:Object = JSON.parse(jsonText);

for(var key:String in jsonObj){
    Alert.show("Key is"+key + " value is "+ jsonObj[key]);
}
```

Your case exactly

```
var myObj:Object = JSON.decode(result);

for(var key:String in myObj){
        Alert.show("Key is"+key + " value is "+ myObj[key]);
    }
```